# Using nodemailer in a React app Post 404 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, nodemailer

I've followed the tutorials I could find online, but I still receiving an error.
I have a contact form in my React app and want the `submit` button to send an email to my personal gmail account using `nodemailer`.

In my app, I have the setup `src/components/contact.js` which contains the Form and submit function

```
export default class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      title: ""
    };
  }


 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("Form Details: ", this.state);

    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/send",
      data: this.state,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.status === "success") {
        alert("Message Sent.");
        this.resetForm();
      } else if (response.data.status === "fail") {
        alert("Message failed to send.");
      }
    });
  }


  resetForm() {
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      email: "",
      title: ""
    });
  }

render() {
return (
<>
 <div className="contactform">

          <form
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
            id="contact-form"
            method="POST"
          >
            <form.Group>

                    <input
                      label="First & Last Name"
                      placeholder="Full name"
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.onNameChange.bind(this)}
                    />

                    <input
                      label="Email"
                      type="email"
                      name="email"
                      value={this.state.email}
                      onChange={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                    />
                    <input
                      label="Title"
                      type="text"
                      name="title"
                      value={this.state.title}
                      onChange={this.onTitleChange.bind(this)}
                    />
                    </form.Group>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
</>
);
}

 onNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  onEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  }

  onTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ title: event.target.value });
  }
```

In my `.env`, I saved my email and password

```
USER = 'mygmail@gmail.com'
PASS = 'mygmail123pass'
```

Then I created a file in `src/config.js` - I'm not sure if this is okay or not, or if the file needs to be under the root directory and not inside `src` folder.

In `config.js`, I have

```
import env from 'react-dotenv';
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var cors = require("cors");

nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: env.USER,
    pass: env.PASS
  },
  debug: true,
  logger: true
});

transporter.verify((error, success) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Server is ready to take messages");
  }
});


router.post("/send", (req, res, next) => {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var title = req.body.title;
  var content = `name: ${name} \n title: ${title}`;

  var mail = {
    from: email,
    to: env.USER,
    subject: "Harp Gig Request",
    text: content,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        status: "fail",
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        status: "success",
      });
    }
  });
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(3000);
```

When I test out my contact form, the error I am getting is this:
[image]

What is wrong in my setup?

Comment: I fixed it to be ```app.listen(3000)```, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Where is the axios `Base Url` configuration?

Comment: @Danizavtz I don't have anything for that.

Comment: Your code does not compile, please paste working code.

Comment: your javascript file and webpage is on 3000 too? Please verify the port of both your front end and backend.

Comment: @Danizavtz I added my full ```contact.js``` file. I'm also using ```semantic-ui```.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial yes, everywhere in my code is localhost:3000 and the webpage

Comment: In my ```.env```, I added ```REACT_APP_BE_URL=https://www.mywebsite.com```, then in ```index.js```, I added ```import axios from 'axios'; axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL;```. but in the ```.env```, do I put my website name on that variable?